# How to call kendra api using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-kendra

i am not able to call the kendra API using reactjs.
i have below details in js only but need help in reactjs:

```
var kendra = new AWS.Kendra();
kendra.batchDeleteDocument(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

please help me.

Comment: What is your ReactJS code ? Could you show the component that you try to call this API ? ReactJS is just plain javascript with support from library, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

For reference you can look at [Deploying Kendra Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/deploying.html) there is an example application in reactjs on how to use Kendra search APIs.

Comment: but it is with local example , not API called

Comment: yep, example is pretty useless. for it to be of real use would have it setup so you could deploy remote using secure credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better/safer if you could have a lambda function to deal with the Kendra query and your reactjs can call the lambda function. In this way, you can control more on the query and others.

Since you also need the kendra index id or other information, it's better to hide them in the lambda.

For example, you can add a simple flask lambda/app:

```
@app.route('/kendra/<method>', methods=['POST'])
def client(method: str):
    kendra = boto3.client('kendra')
    try:
        data = request.get_json(silent=True) or {}
        return jsonify(getattr(kendra, method)(**data))
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': f"{e}"})
```